# Alt History - how do I base an empire on Rome but demonstrate quickly the difference whilst keeping the familiarity?

Tags: world-building

Are there specific tricks, mechanisms or devices to offer a shortcut to a level of civilisation without confusing the reader? I'm using a Ancient Rome-like country but don't want to base the plot in Rome.

Comment: Hi there, as it stands, this is a very broad question and will probably be closed if you cannot refine it. Can you perhaps highlight some of the difficulties you are having? As far as having a Romanesque setting, there's no issue. It's your story, and it's a popular style. Is there any particular aspect you would like to address first?

Answer (score 1):

The Roman Empire was very large, and had many regional differences (which persisted for a long time). Consider the possibility of using a fictional location in the actual Roman Empire. Hardly any readers would know whether the events and incidents of daily life were historically compatible, or not. I am assuming that your story does not involve extraterrestrials or pterodactyls or wizards, or anything else that was definitely not historical.

There is a series of fiction, vaguely along the lines of detective novels, set in the height of the Roman Empire. I read one, but cannot recall the author. Actual places and famous persons of the time are mentioned. Daily incidents, and plot events, sound plausible for the era. But I have no idea whether the locals actually lived that way, or not.